# Can't use .toPandas() or .collect() after applying pandas udf: IndexError

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am using pandasUDF to apply standard ML python libraries to pyspark DataFrame. After defining the schema and making predictions I get the pyspark DF as an output.
Now, I want to do some stuff with this predictions dataframe, e.g. I try to sum up all the values in the column "weekly_forecast_1". When I apply .collect() or .toPandas() methods, I get the following error in .fit()

```
IndexError: too many indices for array:array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed
```

I get the above error whenever I try to apply .collect() or .toPandas() methods to the whole DataFrame or to some of its columns. I tried to make a copy of DF and the apply the methods, but it results in the same error.

P.S. the error is the same for different ML libraries (e.g. statsmodels.ExponentialSmoothing, fbprophet, sklearn RandomForestRegressor etc)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To improve your question, please add a (possibly simplified) code snippet so that we can see what you are doing. Otherwise, it is hard to help you with anything.

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
IndexError: too many indices for array:array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed
```

means that you are trying to index an array with too many indices for its dimensions. Here, it seems that your array is 0-dimensional (meaning it is a scalar) and you try to index it.

Since the error is the same for multiple different libraries I think your problem comes from the UDF, and I would guess it is not returning what you expect. It probably return just a scalar inside the DF instead of a regular matrix.